# Limit the (loud only) volume output from speakers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio

When you turn down volume it tunes down the **loud** noises as well as the **soft** noises.

I would like to limit only the **loud** noises.

The system "knows" how loud the volume is: it displays the volume level by those white lines:

[image: showing volume output level]

I would like a way to limit the number of white lines so never pass beyond X lines (white lines as shown in GIF, but in reality I guess it would be an Integer).

All I could find was lowering or limiting the entire volume button but that would make the **soft** noises low as well- Again I just want to lower the **loud** noises.

So for example at an action movie: When people are talking do nothing but when there's shooting and explosives, then limit their volume output if "it's too loud" (volume output is beyond X number of white lines).

Current situation: my family sleeps the next room, I watch an action movie:
people talk in the movie- I need certain amount of volume to hear them, but then at the actions scenes I'm forced to turn down the volume but then when people are talking again- I can't hear them so I need to turn up the volumn again.

I would like:
If my family is sleeping in the next room I would be able to watch a movie without touching the volume button- it will only limit the volume when it is **loud** but not when it is **soft**

Any ideas?
My OS is `PopOS 20.04` which is basically `Ubuntu 20.04`

P.S I don't like headphones -.-

EDIT:

To clarify: I'm not a musician nor do I know any audio/recording tools,
I just want to watch youtube / home videos without waking up my family next door, while still using speakers (no headphones)

- I would like a **software** solution to limit (only) the loud volume in real time
- And if for some reason there isn't one available at 2020, then maybe (a not expensive, not complicated) hardware solution, But I mean- it's 2020 - there must be a simple (at least not complicated) software solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is known in the world of audio and music processing as a **compressor** or **limiter**.

Rather than "turn down" only the loud parts of your audio signal, which of course are not really separate "parts" by the time your system is playing them, a compressor/limiter processes the signal as a whole and constrains its dynamic range. The effect is that however loud the input volume goes at any point, the output volume  never exceeds a certain level.

There are a range of audio processors in this category with similar or overlapping behaviour, including the **compander**, which boosts quiet sounds as well as limiting loud ones, producing a flatter dynamic range. This is reminiscent of the automatic gain control found on some recording devices.

Although less faithful to the original sound, audio processing of this kind can have practical benefits, both in scenarios such as your own, and also when listening in in noisy environments, when background noise can otherwise mean quiet passages are hard to hear.

For an example of free linux audio processing software, try https://compressor-limiter.winsite.com/linux/.

On a wider note, it should be pointed out that **solid state electronic** compressors, limiters and companders preexist their software equivalents, and are still readily available today at low cost in the form of [guitar effects pedals](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=guitar%20compressor) and suchlike. So you could quite easily route your sound to an external amplifier and speakers (such as an old hifi setup) via one of these. The guitar effects boxes tend to use 1/4 inch jack connectors, but adaptors between jack and other audio connectors are easy to find.

Comment: Thanks, searching for compressors or limiters all I could find was various plugins to audio programs, but not a standalone software. Also download link for your example is broken

Comment: @Roko I have no control over that site unfortunately. I take it you found a download link for something but it wasn't working just then. Perhaps it will work on another occasion. But that site's just an example to give a feel for what's possible. On plugins, probably you can achieve what you need using an app (Audacity or somesuch) that can take plugins and which also allows you to monitor the sound while in a recording mode. On a wider note, I've also updated my answer to mention solid-state electronic compressors, which you may want to consider as an alternative to software signal processing

Comment: edited my question, Like you said I will check a hardware solution but I would prefer software one